# ¿Cómo hacer un order by sobre una columna cuyo tipo de dato es enum?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Tengo una tabla llamada `proyectos`
la cual tiene las siguientes columnas :

- `nombre`
- `estado = [activo, inactivo, cerrado]`
- `fecha_created`
- `fecha_updated`
- `c_users` (fk_usuario)

lo que quiero conseguir es que me obtenga los `proyectos` según el `estado` y de forma `descendente` `fecha_created`, entonces hice esto:

```
$consulta = DB::table('proyecto')->where('c_users',Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('estado')->orderBy('fecha_created','desc')->get();
```

la consulta me soluciona el problema de forma `orderBy('fecha_created','desc')` pero el problema es con `orderBy('estado')` que genera, pero tal cual como lo guarde en el `migrate` :  `activo` , `inactivo` , `cerrado`.

pero quisiera que me muestre de la siguiente forma:
`activos` `cerrados` `inactivos`

como podría generar de la forma que quiero según el estado ?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, si amigo, de hecho eso fue lo primero que hice, pero me di cuenta que si no lo pongo igual lo toma de forma `asc`

Comment: el problema es cambiar el orden entre la segunda y el ultimo estado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si nos basamos en la documentación de MySQL, indica que las mejores formas de hacer un ordenamiento sobre una columna de tipo `ENUM` son:

- Ingresa los valores en la columna en orden alfabético
- Asegúrate de que el ordenamiento sea léxico en lugar de su índice llevando a cabo un cast de los valores

Ejemplo tomado de la documentación oficial<sup>1</sup>

```
ORDER BY CAST(col AS CHAR) or ORDER BY CONCAT(col).
```

Para este caso cómo estás en [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) deberás usar el método

```
orderByRaw(......)
```

Y componer el cast dentro de este método

**Referencia**

- <sup>1</sup> [Mysql docs.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html#enum-sorting)

Comment: por favor podrías ayudarme explicando bien lo de `orderByRaw`, en la documentación de Laravel explican así = `->orderByRaw('updated_at - created_at DESC')` pero esas son dos columnas de la tabla y como seria en el caso de un `enum` y lo de cast dentro no entendí.

Comment: Puedes probar construyendo tu ordenamiento así `->orderByRaw('CAST (estado AS CHAR)')`

Comment: olvide aprobarla, gracias BetaM.